# curl in PHP behave diferrently in the same DOM pages

Tags: php, dom, curl, simpledom

I run below code and it worked, but I see blank screen when I try with this URL : https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/3aguyp/i_told_my_boyfriend_the_new_puppy_wasnt_allowed/

```
<?php include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = getSslPage('https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/3a53qw/grandmother_mother_and_daughter/');


function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$html = str_get_html($html);

echo $html;
```

The 2 page have the same DOM structure.

Comment: You're doing two things; which one cause the issue?

Comment: page size can be the issue. you must to change the default size below 

define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000);  or define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10000000); (It's on the top of the simple_html_dom.php)